# NameError: name 'os_PathLike' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, numpy-ndarray

I wanted to load text into a numpy array. I have used the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import os

a = np.loadtxt(os.getcwd()+'abc.txt')
```

But I am getting an error as follows:

File "/Users/vivekchowdary/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 965, in loadtxt

NameError: name 'os_PathLike' is not defined

Can anyone help me with what's going wrong with my code?

Comment: what version of numpy are you using? You can get it via `np.__version__`.

Comment: My version is 1.17.2